# Tailwind CSS works on the default Gatsby example but not gatsby-starter-blog

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, tailwind-css

I tried making a basic site using the default Gatsby example project using Tailwind CSS, and it worked perfectly. Now, I'm trying to copy my index page from the default project into the new project based on gatsby-starter-blog. Everything is fine (after also copying the layout.js as a new file and importing that into my index.js), other than that Tailwind no longer works.

The code for my index.js is below:

```
import * as React from "react";

import Layout from "../components/layout-index";
import Seo from "../components/seo";

const IndexPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Seo title="Home" />
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-4xl flex justify-center text-purple-400">hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p className="justify-left flex-auto flex-wrap">
        This is my first attempt at creating a website.
      </p>
      <p className="justify-left flex-auto flex-wrap">
        If you've stuck around long enough to read this, you might as well check
        out my <a href="./blog">blog.</a> Thanks!
      </p>
    </div>
  </Layout>
);

export default IndexPage;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed and configured all the files to use [Tailwind in Gatsby](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/gatsby)?

In your Gatsby configuration:

```
// gatsby-config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-postcss',
    // ...
  ],
}
```

And your Tailwing configuration:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Add the base Tailwind components in `./src/styles/global.css`

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Import the previous file in the `gatsby-browser.js`:

```
import './src/styles/global.css'
```